# Removing the "drag and drop ghost element" on drop in Vue 3

Tags: html, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I'm using Vue but without a DnD library, just the native functionality.
Everything is working beautifully except that on drop, even when it's a successful drop, the ghost element rubber bands back to the original position.

When a drop is successful, I don't want it to snap back to the original position.

Is there a way that I can prevent the default ghost animation that happens on drop?

```html
<section id="board" class="rounded-md flex overflow-x-auto">
      <div
        @dragover="dragOverHandler(col)"
        id="board-cols"
        :ref="col"
        class="whitespace-nowrap w-72 mx-2 px-2"
        :class="toStatus === col ? 'bg-gray-200' : ''"
        v-for="(col, i) in columns"
        :key="i"
      >
        <div
          id="col-header"
          class="w-full bg-blue-200"
          :class="toStatus === col && 'bg-gray-200 font-semibold'"
        >
          {{ col }}
        </div>

        <div
          :draggable="true"
          @dragstart="dragStartHandler"
          @dragend="dragEndHandler(item)"
          v-for="(item, j) in collections[col]"
          id="data"
          :key="j"
          class="flex flex-col my-2 rounded-xl overflow-hidden select-none cursor-move"
        >
          <EventPreviewCard :event="item" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the default functionality of dragenter and dragover on the dropzone. Adding `@dragenter.prevent` and `@dragover.prevent` fixed the problem.

```html
     <div
        @dragenter.prevent
        @dragover.prevent
        @dragover="dragOverHandler(col)"
        id="board-cols"
        :ref="col"
        class="whitespace-nowrap w-72 mx-2 px-2"
        :class="toStatus === col && 'bg-gray-200'"
        v-for="(col, i) in columns"
        :key="i"
      >
```

Very strange default behavior in my opinion.